# Haxe generating super call with arguments

Tags: macros, haxe

The context is type-building macro. My goal is to generate

```
super(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

What I have:

```
Array<FunctionArg> => [{ meta => null, name => foo, type => TPath({ name => StdTypes, pack => [], params => [], sub => Int }), opt => null, value => null },{ meta => null, name => bar, type => TPath({ name => StdTypes, pack => [], params => [], sub => Int }), opt => null, value => null }]
```

I've tried `macro super($a{ancestorArgs})` but that's just silly, as `$a` expects `Array<Expr>`.

I have no ideas left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var args = [ for ( arg in funcArgs ) macro $i { arg.name } ];
func.expr = macro 
{
    super( $a{ args } );
};
```